# How can i see the drawing in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I drawed triangle but I can't see on storyboard. How can I see on storyboard this drawing ?

[image]
View Controller Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var fooView: UIView!

    var polygonShape = CAShapeLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let polygonPath = UIBezierPath()
        polygonPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: -1))
        polygonPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 93.3, y: 74))
        polygonPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 6.7, y: 74))
        polygonPath.close()

        polygonShape.frame = fooView.bounds
        polygonShape.path = polygonPath.cgPath

        fooView.layer.mask = polygonShape

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want a triangle pointing up?

Comment: Yes sir. I want to see drawing on storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your class to this:

```
@IBDesignable
class FirstImageView: UIView {

    var polygonShape: CAShapeLayer!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        if polygonShape == nil {
            polygonShape = CAShapeLayer()
            layer.mask = polygonShape
        }

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let polygonPath = UIBezierPath()
        polygonPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: bounds.size.height))
        polygonPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width * 0.5, y: 0.0))
        polygonPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width, y: bounds.size.height))
        polygonPath.close()

        polygonShape.path = polygonPath.cgPath
    }

}
```

You can remove ***everything*** from your `ViewController` class. You don't even need the class at all at this point.

Select the view on your Storyboard, and at the top of the `Identity Inspector` pane change the `Custom Class` from the default `UIView` to `FirstImageView`.

Under the top `Editor` menu, either select `Refresh All Views` or make sure `Automatically Refresh Views` is checked.

Result:

[image]